# How to get a table-level check constraint in Oracle and PostgreSQL

Tags: oracle, postgresql, constraints

I want to know if there is some specific way to obtain a table-level check constraint in Oracle and in PostgreSQL.

I can obtain all the check constraints in a table, but I want to obtain only this specific check constraint, I don't know if there is any specific query.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In PostgreSQL there is a System Catalog [pg_constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/catalog-pg-constraint.html).

> The catalog pg_constraint stores check, primary key, unique, foreign
>   key, and exclusion constraints on tables. (Column constraints are not
>   treated specially. Every column constraint is equivalent to some table
>   constraint.) Not-null constraints are represented in the pg_attribute
>   catalog, not here.
>
> User-defined constraint triggers (created with CREATE CONSTRAINT
>   TRIGGER) also give rise to an entry in this table.
>
> Check constraints on domains are stored here, too.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    pg_constraint
WHERE
    contype = 'c' AND   -- check constraint
    conrelid != 0 AND   -- table constraint
    conname = 'my_check';
```

The `contype` column contains the constraint type, `c` is for check constraint.
The `conrelid` column contains the `oid` of the table this constraint is on, `0` if not a table constraint.

Comment: Thank so much for your answer, I am looking for an specific query for only check constraint tab-level, I don't know if it exists. With this query I obtain all the constraint, no only tab-level check constraint.

Comment: OK, I've updated my answer to select only table check constraints. Please, explain what you mean by "specific check constraint". Do you want to find missing checks?

Comment: I don't know if I am explaining good, I only want the table-level check constraint where I don't know the name of the conname. For example: I have a table EMP with 2 variables called BONUS and TAX and I have a table-level check constraint where I have BONUS > TAX. I only want this constraint but if I look in pg_constraint whit that query I can't diferenciate if it is a table-level check constraint or a column-level check constraint. I don't know if I have explained it very good, sorry!

Comment: There is a `consrc` column (a human-readable representation of the check constraint) in `pg_constraint`. Maybe try `... WHERE consrc ILIKE '%BONUS > TAX%';`

Comment: Yes, it is the problem, if I try `... WHERE consrc LIKE...` I obtain column-level check constraint and I want it more general, where I don't know the constraint. Thank for all!

Answer (score -1):

For Oracle basic view is [ALL_CONSTRAINTS](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_1037.htm#i1576022)

Query, to obtain specific constraint in specific table:

```
SELECT *
  FROM all_constraints
 WHERE constraint_name LIKE upper('%&your_costraint%')
   AND table_name LIKE upper('%&your_table%');
```

Comment: Thank so much, I am looking for a specific query for only check constraint tab_level without knowing the constraint name. In your way I obtain all the constraint in a table.

Comment: Use column **constraint_type** to find only check constraints: `SELECT * FROM all_constraints WHERE table_name LIKE upper('%&your_table%') AND constraint_type = 'C';`